# Convert java java.util.UUID and save it into PostgreSQL UUID

Tags: postgresql, jpa, uuid, converters

I have this `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` because I need to store UUID (v4) into PostgreSQL. Converting database entity into local entity works well, but I cannot convert local entity back to database column - [UUID Postgresql type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-uuid.html).

```
@Converter
public final class ApiClientIdAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ApiClientId, UUID> {

  @Override
  public UUID convertToDatabaseColumn(ApiClientId attribute) {
    return ofNullable(attribute.getIdValue())
        .map(entityUuid -> attribute.getIdValue())
        .orElse(null);
  }

  @Override
  public ApiClientId convertToEntityAttribute(UUID dbData) {
    return new ApiClientId(dbData);
  }

}
```

An exception:

> 10:32:59.960 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column
>   "api_client_id" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko Added.

Comment: why not start by defining the DDL for the table where this is stored? and post the entity while you're at it